# .NET Web API - Error Response with ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm building an API in C# with .NET Web API 2.2. I'm validating the request and returning an 'error' response via ModelState.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<CustomerModel>))]
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromBody]List<CustomerSearchModel> row)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        CustomerLookupModel model = new CustomerLookupModel(row);
        model.Init();
        model.Load();

        return Ok(model.Customers);
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

Here is a sample 'error' response.

```
{
    "message": "The request is invalid.",
    "modelState": {
        "row[0].Country": ["'Country' should not be empty."]
    }
}
```

In the 'error' response, I would like to change the word 'modelState' to 'error'.  I thought I could do that by copying the 'ModelState' object and naming it 'error'... and include that with BadRequest.

```
return BadRequest(error);
```

That didn't work.  I must be missing something simple.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Return anonymous object:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage GetModelStateErrors()
    {

        //return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new Product());

        ModelState.AddModelError("EmployeeId", "Employee Id is required.");
        ModelState.AddModelError("EmployeeId", "Employee Id should be integer");
        ModelState.AddModelError("Address", "Address is required");
        ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Email is required");
        ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Invalid Email provided.");

        var error = new {
            message = "The request is invalid.",
            error = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(e=> e.Errors.Select(er=>er.ErrorMessage))
        };

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, error);
    }
```

Fiddler output:

[image]

Comment: Hello... i don't understand your answer.  ModelState is dictionary. I ended up using this approach - http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/a-better-validation-result-for-asp-net-webapi

Comment: Sorry, What I meant was to return an anonymous object. Dint actually meant to use that code, my bad. I have updated the code.

Comment: @Bill link is broken